# Center UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to fix a small issue with my UICollectionView, when on the 6s device size I get a layout like this:

[image]

However, I want to know what is the best way to either center them so that its two lines, or should i shrink them down a bit so I can put three of them? I think I would prefer to center the two columns instead so I'm not cramming too much onto the same screen. I looked but wasn't sure what to do with the Layout formatting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe one or both of these are what you are looking for. Play with the values you return and see what happens. Also, your constraint inside each cell will have some effect that I can not predict without seeing them.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionView, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```